# React setState returns function dispatch()

Tags: reactjs

I have met issues setting the state of the const `displayClipName` in the following function which is blocking despite the fact that I passed the props from the parent element to the child.

```
const audioClips = [
        {
        keyCode: 67,
        keyTrigger: "C",
        id: "Closed-HH",
        src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"
    }
]


function App() {

    const [displayClipName, setDisplayClipName] = React.useState('Click a key!')  
    

    return (
    <div id="drum-machine" className="text-white text-center">
             <div className="container bg-info">
                <h1>FCC - Drum Machine</h1>
                {audioClips.map((clip) => (
                <Pad 
                    key={clip.id}
                    clip={clip}
                    setDisplayClipName={setDisplayClipName}                
                />
                ))}
                <h2>{displayClipName}</h2>
              </div>
    </div>
    )
}



const Pad = ({clip, setDisplayClipName}) => {
    const [playing, setPlaying] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKey)
        }
    }, [])

    const handleKey = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode === clip.keyCode) {
            playSound()
            }
    }

    const playSound = () => {
        const audioPlay = document.getElementById(clip.keyTrigger);
        const clipName = document.getElementById(clip.id)
        setPlaying(true);
        setTimeout(() => setPlaying(false), 300);
        audioPlay.currentTime = 0; 
        audioPlay.play();
        setDisplayClipName(clipName);
        console.log(setDisplayClipName)
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={playSound} id={`drum-pad-${clip.keyTrigger}`}>
            <audio src={clip.src} className="clip" id={clip.keyTrigger}/>
            {clip.keyTrigger}
        </div>
        
    )
}

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

The console returns the following message:

```
function dispatchSetState()
​
length: 1
​
name: "bound dispatchSetState"
​
<prototype>: function ()
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You should use [refs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs) to access dom elements in React. Also move the `handleKey` inside the `useEffect` currently it will create a new reference of the function every render which might cause memory issues since the `useEffect` using the function is only run once.

Comment: You're logging `setDisplayClipName` (the setter function) and not `displayClipName` (the state value), so I'm not really sure what you're expecting. Furthermore, also if you logged the value of `displayClipName`, you likely wouldn't see the correct value as setState is asynchronous, so you'd be logging it before it was updated. You could do something like `useEffect(()=>{console.log(displayClipName)}, [displayClipName])` to log `displayClipName` whenever it changes.

Comment: I would like that displayClipName displays the id of the audioClips which has been clicked. However, most of the magic (playSound, event listener, ...) happens in the Pad component and I can't figure out how to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some have pointed out in comments to your post it'd be better if you used [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Also you were logging a function that's why the console displayed that. I have taken the liberty to do some modifications to your code so I could understand it better, I would suggest you keep the ones you find reasonable:

- The `displayName` variable has an `undefined` state when no song is playing. This could be set from any other part of the application but you wouldn't depend on rerendering the component for it to return to a default message ("Press a key!")
- The `playSound` function could be bound to the `id` of the song and you would avoid having to check the HTML element that received the input.

Here is a working snippet.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const audioClips = [
  {
    keyCode: 67,
    keyTrigger: "C",
    id: "Closed-HH",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"
  }
]

const Pad = ({ clip, setDisplayClipName }) => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleKey = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === clip.keyCode) {
      playSound(clip.id);
    }
  };

  const playSound = (clipId) => {
    const audioPlay = document.getElementById(clip.keyTrigger);
    setPlaying(true);
    setTimeout(() => setPlaying(false), 300);
    audioPlay.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlay.play();
    setDisplayClipName(clipId);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={() => playSound(clip.id)} id={`drum-pad-${clip.keyTrigger}`}>
      <audio src={clip.src} className="clip" id={clip.keyTrigger} />
      {clip.keyTrigger}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [clipName, setClipName] = useState(undefined);

  return (
    <div id="drum-machine" className="text-white text-center">
      <div className="container bg-info">
        <h1>FCC - Drum Machine</h1>
        {audioClips.map((clip) => (
          <Pad key={clip.id} clip={clip} setDisplayClipName={setClipName} />
        ))}
        <h2>{clipName ? clipName : "Press a key!"}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

To further refine the `Pad` component and avoid the missing dependencies on the `useEffect` hook I would suggest you model it like this, using `useMemo`:

```js
export const Pad = ({ clip, setDisplayClipName }) => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const playSound = useMemo(
    () => () => {
      const audioPlay = document.getElementById(clip.keyTrigger);
      setPlaying(true);
      setTimeout(() => setPlaying(false), 300);
      if (audioPlay) {
        audioPlay.currentTime = 0;
        audioPlay.play();
      }
      setDisplayClipName(clip.id);
    },
    [setDisplayClipName, clip]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKey = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === clip.keyCode) {
        playSound();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
    };
  }, [playSound, clip.keyCode]);

  return (
    <div onClick={playSound} id={`drum-pad-${clip.keyTrigger}`}>
      <audio src={clip.src} className="clip" id={clip.keyTrigger} />
      {clip.keyTrigger}
    </div>
  );
};
```